# Evaluation of precomputed clustering using ELKI in Java

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, data-mining, elki

I already have computed clusters and want to use ELKI library only to perform evaluation on this clustering.

So I have data in this form:

```
0.234 0.923 cluster_1 true_cluster1
0.543 0.874 cluster_2 true_cluster3
...
```

I tried to:

1. Create 2 databases: with result labels and with reference labels:

   ```
   double [][] data;
   String [] reference_labels, result_labels;

   DatabaseConnection dbc1 = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(data, result_labels);
   Database db1 = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc1, null);

   DatabaseConnection dbc2 = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(data, reference_labels);
   Database db2 = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc2, null);
   ```
2. Perform ByLabel Clustering for each database:

   ```
   Clustering<Model> clustering1 = new ByLabelClustering().run(db1);
   Clustering<Model> clustering2 = new ByLabelClustering().run(db2);
   ```
3. Use ClusterContingencyTable for comparing clusterings and getting measures:

   ```
   ClusterContingencyTable ct = new ClusterContingencyTable(true, false);
   ct.process(clustering1, clustering2);
   PairCounting paircount = ct.getPaircount();
   ```

The problem is that measuers are not computed.
I looked into source code of ContingencyTable and PairCounting and it seems that it won't work if clusterings come from different databases  and a database can have only 1 labels relation.
Is there a way to do this in ELKI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `ByLabelClustering` class easily (or implement your own) to only use the first label, or only use the second label; then you can use only one database.

Or you use the 3-parameter constructor:

```
DatabaseConnection dbc1 = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(data, result_labels, 0);
Database db1 = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc1, null);

DatabaseConnection dbc2 = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(data, reference_labels, 0);
Database db2 = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc2, null);
```

so that the DBIDs are the same. Then `ClusterContingencyTable` should work.

By default, ELKI would *continue* enumerating objects, so the first database would have IDs 1..n, and the second n+1..2n. But in order to compare clusterings, they need to contain the same objects, not disjoint sets.

Comment: Using the 3-parameter constructor did the trick. Thank you for reply.